# Is there a difference between 風景 and 風光？

Tags: difference

Our book just introduced 風景 as scenic view, landscape. Now it introduces 風光 as "scenery". The book is very basic. It typically doesn't introduce alternative vocabulary. So I am trying to spot any differences.

Would you perhaps use 風光 in a city and 風景 in nature? Like:

> 天色很藍，雲都反映落日的紅光，落日時的北京真是一個漂亮的風光。

Or:

> 西湖上有一座白色的橋，湖邊的樹很多，樹下的花紅紅綠綠，落日時的西湖真是一的漂亮的風景。

Feel free to correct. The sentences are mine and I always make mistakes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

「風」 in 「風景」 and 「風光」 carries the meaning of :

1. 'Style': as in 「和風」 (Japanese style) and 「作風」(style of behavior)
2. 'air; atmosphere' - (something that creates moods and evokes feelings)

「景」 in 「風景」 carries the meaning of  'scene/ sight' -- the picture you see in your eyes, as in 「奇景」(strange sight)，「場景」(scene in a play)

> The term 「風景」 (sight/ scenery) **specifically** refers to 'the sight of a landscape or a natural scenery'  as in 「看風景」(watching the natural scenery )

「光」in 「風光」refers to 'light', which is needed to enable people to see -- in another word: 'sight'.

> The term「風光」 **generally** refers to 'sight/ scene /scenery'

For example:「異國**風光**」(sights and scenes of foreign country) ;「園林**風光**」(sights and scenes of garden and forest)

Of course it includes 'landscape or a natural setting' For example:
「西湖**風光**」. Therefore 「風光」and「風景」are interchangeable in this sense. (*You can write 「西湖**風景**」instead of 「西湖**風光**」*)

Unlike 「風景」, 「風光」can also be used metaphorically.

- 「**風光**大葬」(scenic funeral = **impressive, dignified** funeral)
- 「**風光**了幾十年」( have been a sight to behold for decades = have been **awesome** for decades)