# What is the difference in usage between 风光，景色 and 风景?

Tags: meaning, difference

风光 scene; view; sight

景色 view; scene; landscape

风景 scenery; landscape

People on other websites suggest there's no difference. Is that so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already answered this question here: [Is there a difference between 風景 and 風光？](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/24096/is-there-a-difference-between-%e9%a2%a8%e6%99%af-and-%e9%a2%a8%e5%85%89/24097#24097)

As for 景色:

「景」 in 「景色」 carries the meaning of 'scene/ sight' -- the picture you see in your eyes, as in  「景物」(sight and things), 「景象」(scene; image)

「色」in 「景色」 carries the meaning of 'color/ appearance' as in 「山光水色」(sight of the mountains and appearance of the water = scenery of mountains and river, lake or ocean )

> The term「**風光**」 generally refers to '**sight**/ **scene** /**scenery**' (*natural or man made*)

~

> The term 「**景色**」 generally refers to "**sight/ scene /scenery**" (*natural or man made*)

~

> The term 「**風景**」 specifically refers to '**the sight** of a landscape or a natural scenery'

~

*「西湖**風景**」,「西湖**風光**」or「西湖**景色**」all mean "**scenery** of the West Lake"*